# Setting StartActivity in swipeview

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener, swipe-gesture

I am trying to make a swipe view with a button in it and when ever the button is clicked it will open a second activity but i am not able to set setActivity in the on click listener Here is my code.what changes will i do in my pager adapter

```
package com.example.neelaysrivastava.imageswipe;

   import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomeSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] image_resource={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4,R.drawable.img5,R.drawable.img6} ;
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
public CustomeSwipeAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.ctx=ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_resource.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)object );
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.second,container,false);
    ImageView imageView =(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Button button=(Button)item_view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_resource[position]);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}
```

}

Comment: Why you are not able to make Intent in your onClick method.. i think that there are no problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set onclick in xml for the button and called it

```
public void anything(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Some.class));
}
```

It will do the work.Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `interface` and register it in button click listener and implement that interface in your activity and pass the instance of that interface in to your `CustomeSwipeAdapter` constructor.